# Using CherryPy as a blocking/non-threading server for easier debugging

Tags: python, debugging, cherrypy

Is it possible to use the CherrPy server as a blocking/non-threading server (for easier debugging?)

Answer (score 3):

No. Not only does the wsgiserver start its own set of worker threads (10 by default, but even if you only specified 1 that's still 1 thread for the listening socket and 1 worker thread). Even if that were not true, if you use the rest of CherryPy (i.e. the engine), it runs that 1 listener thread in a separate thread from the main thread.